# Regex for Detecting the Text Inside of <a></a> Tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that finds the text between HTML anchor tags in my string of text. The text is comparable to a Tweet, so a sample string would be:

```
   http://google.com is great, but http://www.stackoverflow.com may be my only hope. www.yahoo.com is out of the question.
```

Which runs through my working regexps:

```
function processTweetLinks(text) {
       console.log(text);
           text = text.replace();

   var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2;

   //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
   replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
   text = text.replace(replacePattern1, '<a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

   //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
   replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
   text = text.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

   console.log(text);
   return text;
   }
```

And comes out as:

```
  <a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a> is great, but <a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a> may be my only hope. <a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">www.yahoo.com</a> is out of the question.
```

I want another line or two that grabs what's betweenthe `<a></a>` tags, finds the beginning of links (for instance, `http://`, `https://`, `http://www`., `https://www.`), and removes them, leaving the shortest possible text that's still recognizable as a link to the user ("`google.com`"). I have a regexp that seems to correctly sift through the text and finds those things between the `<a></a>` tags, and not in the href. Here's the expression:

```
   (?:<a [^>]+>.*?)(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/){0,1}(www\.))(?:.*?<\/a>)

`http://` and `https://` are in `$2`, and `www.` is in `$3`. How would I use this in the context of my function?
```

Comment: You should probably use the DOM for this... Seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)?

Answer (score 0):

Using dom parsing makes it simple. You can apply any regex if you want to remove `http://` etc from this

```
$('a').each(function(){
  alert(this.href);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/y6LUg/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If there's some way to avoid regex completely, please, enlighten me! I never want to see a regexp again.

Comment: @tylerl Even I don't understand why this is down voted. Hope adding comments for down vote becomes a rule at some time

Comment: I was hop-ing (sorry) you could expand on this a bit further. Away from the computer right now but I tried to apply a .filter along with your .each thing, but I couldn't figure out how & where to apply my regexp... I'll explain myself better when I get the chance but this is bugging the hell out of me...